# Facing issues while implementing google API to Angular

Tags: angular, google-pay, payment-request-api

I am intergrating google pay api to one of my angular project and trying to add the options into the code. but not be able to do that. error coming is `error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 3.`. but in W3C it is code is  `new PaymentRequest(methodData, details, options);`. you can find the document here [2.4 Constructing a PaymentRequest](https://www.w3.org/TR/payment-request/#constructing-a-paymentrequest)

- Code snippets

[image: Payment request snippet]

- W3C document code

```
async function doPaymentRequest() {
  try {
---->>>>    const request = new PaymentRequest(methodData, details, options);
    const response = await request.show();
    await validateResponse(response);
  } catch (err) {
    // AbortError, SecurityError
    console.error(err);
  }
}
async function validateResponse(response) {
  try {
    const errors = await checkAllValuesAreGood(response);
    if (errors.length) {
      await response.retry(errors);
      return validateResponse(response);
    }
    await response.complete("success");
  } catch (err) {
    // Something went wrong...
    await response.complete("fail");
  }
}
// Must be called as a result of a click
// or some explicit user action.
doPaymentRequest();
```

I am actually not be able to find the way to pass the third params inside angular.

Comment: In the documentation you linked, the constructor has indeed only 2 parameters

Comment: @CarlitosJan you are right but in w3c and mdn docs they have mensioned that we can use both

Please refer this --- ```https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PaymentRequest/PaymentRequest```

Comment: I just need a way to pass three params anyhow